# ckeditor 4.9.2 instanceDestroyed event not getting fired

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I have upgraded ckeditor from 4.4.6 to 4.9.2. After upgrading, it is observed that the 'instanceDestroyed' event of the editor is not getting fired. My application has subscribed to the different events of the editor like  'instanceCreated', 'instanceReady' and 'instanceDestroyed'. Except 'instanceDestroyed', the remaining events are getting triggered as expected. The code for the event 'instanceDestroyed' looks like below:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceDestroyed', function(event) {
    editorState[event.editor.name] = "DESTROYED" ;      
});
```

Any suggestion to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As to [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_plugins_widget_repository.html#event-instanceDestroyed), it's not supposed to trigger on CKEDITOR instance. You must listen to widgets repository changes, like so:

```
CKEDITOR.widgets.on( 'instanceDestroyed', function(event) {
   editorState[event.editor.name] = "DESTROYED" ;      
});
```